# Codeblocks and Qt -- how to work with them?

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

I am new to codeblocks and Qt. I would like to create some nice interfaces with buttons, lists, combo box and so on using Qt. Can someone help me, give me some links from where I can start my journey? I didn't find anywhere how to include qt designer in codeblocks in order to work with it.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S I am working in Ubuntu. I did install code::blocks 10.05 . I also have QT Designer, Creator, LInguist and Assistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have Qt Creator, you don't need anything else unless you have any specific preference for Code::Blocks or any other IDEs.

Qt Creator has an integrated debugging interface too (somewhat similar to Visual Studio).

Here is the [Qt Creator manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.1/index.html) and here you can find details on [How to manage projects using Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.1/creator-project-managing.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you already have all the Qt tools (Creator, Designer, etc.) then why not just use Qt Creator?

It is a wonderful little IDE and is perfect for Qt developing. I actually prefer using it on Ubuntu (on Windows I use the VS Add-In for VS 2010).

The only thing that takes getting used to is adding dependencies which you must directly edit the .pro file for. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html